# Update CSV to Google Sheet's

Tags: csv, google-sheets, gspread, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to import about a 15,000 row csv file to a google sheet that we use.

I thought the import csv would work but i can figure out how to write it to make it work.

any help would be great.

to clarify i am trying to get a raspberry pi to update it via python.

Answer (score 0):

upload your csv file in google drive. right click on csv file and select open with google sheets. it will load your csv data in google sheet and you can also download as xlsx in google sheets